# SQL select a column twice

Tags: php, post

Please help: Why is the below code returning an error in $error_message?

My `$_POST` is:

```
Array
(
    [preferred_district1] => Bubi
    [preferred_district2] => Buhera
    [gender] => Male
    [user_first_name] => Kelvin
    [user_last_name] => Tash
    [mobile_number] => 77589655
    [ec_number] => TAS4752
    [user_email] => tash@gmail.com
    [user_password] => tash
    [blank] => 
    [level_taught] => Primary - ECD
    [current_province] => Harare
    [current_district] => Goromonzi
    [current_school] => SEKE 3 HIGH
)
```

My code is here:

```
if (empty($error_message) && (isset($_POST["preferred_district1"]) || 
    isset($_POST["preferred_district2"])) && 
        (($_POST["preferred_district1"] || $_POST["preferred_district2"]) == 
        $_POST["current_district"])){
            $error_message = 'Invalid form input: Preferred District may not 
             be the same as Current District';
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (empty($error_message) && (isset($_POST["preferred_district1"]) || 
    isset($_POST["preferred_district2"])) && 
    ( ( ($_POST["preferred_district1"]  ==  $_POST["current_district"]) 
        || ($_POST["preferred_district2"]  ==  $_POST["current_district"])
        )
    )
)
{
    $error_message = 'Invalid form input: Preferred District may not 
                 be the same as Current District';
}
```

You have made the mistake in if condition with `or(||)`.

While checking 2 different variables with `or(||)` you need to check it individually as I did here.

Answer (score 0):

The condition return true, you have the `preferred_district2` field and the `preferred_district1` field. 
Probably your problem is the **or** (||) operation. Cause if one of the conditions between the OR operation is true, ot return true.